# How to implement list multiSelect in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, multi-select, android-actionmode

I need to implement multiselect for `LazyList`, which will also change appBar content when list items are long clicked.

For `ListView` we could do that with just setting choiceMode to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` and setting `MultiChoiceModeListener`.

Is there a way to do this using Compose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in control of the whole state in jetpack compose, you can easily create your own multi-select mode. This is an example.

1. First I created a ViewModel

   ```
    val dirs: LiveData<DirViewState> = {
        DirViewState.Content(dirRepository.targetFolders)}.asFlow().asLiveData()

    val all: LiveData<DirViewState> = {
        DirViewState.Content(dirRepository.allFolders)
    }.asFlow().asLiveData()

    val createFolder = mutableStateOf(false)

    val refresh = mutableStateOf(false)

    val enterSelectMode = mutableStateOf(false)

    val selectedAll = mutableStateOf(false)

    val selectedList = mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<String>())


    fun updateList(path: String){
        if(path in selectedList.value){
            selectedList.value.remove(path)
        }else{
            selectedList.value.add(path)
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Usage

   ```
     Card(modifier = Modifier
        .width(100.dp)
        .height(120.dp)
        .padding(8.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onLongPress = { **viewModel.enterSelectMode.value = true** },
                onTap = {
                    if (viewModel.enterSelectMode.value) {
                        viewModel.enterSelectMode.value = false
                    }
                }
            )
        }

        ,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
    ) {

        Image(painter = if (dirModel.dirCover != "") painter
    else painterResource(id = R.drawable.thumbnail),
        contentDescription = "dirThumbnail",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight)

        **AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = viewModel.enterSelectMode.value,
            enter = expandIn(),
            exit = shrinkOut()
        ){
            Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
                Checkbox(checked = isSelected.value, onCheckedChange = {
                    isSelected.value = !isSelected.value
                    viewModel.updateList(dirModel.dirPath)
                })
            }
        }**
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Add `selected` field to some class representing the item. Then just compose proper code based on that field. In compose you don't have to look for some `LazyColumn` flag or anything like that. You are in control of the whole state of the list.

The same can be said about the AppBar, you can do a simple if there, like `if (items.any { it.selected }) // display button`

Comment: Compose doesn't react properly to changes in the data handled outside of composable function, so modifying object representing the item won't help here.

Comment: @noktigula of course, but what is the problem here? It's standard practice to modify objects and then notify compose that they changed. Lazy column will recompose objects that have changed (if those objects implement equality properly). Either way your comment does not make sense in the context of this thread..

Comment: "Compose doesn't react properly to changes in the data handled outside of composable function" this is not 100% accurate. Compose does react well, by recomposing which is the whole point of compose. You change the full-state, push it down, and let compose well... "recompose" what is needed. @noktigula your comment is strange, what are you trying to say? Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle this by the below code:
Fore example This is your list:

```
        LazyColumn {
        items(items = filters) { item ->
            FilterItem(item)
        }
    }
```

and this is your list item View:

```
@Composable
fun FilterItem(filter: FilterModel) {

   val (selected, onSelected) = remember {  mutableStateOf(false) }

   Card(
     shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
     modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            colorResource(
                if (selected)
                    R.color.black
                else
                    R.color.white
            ),
            RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        )) {

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .toggleable(
                value =
                selected,
                onValueChange =
                onSelected
            )
            .padding(8.dp),
    text = filter.text)
}
```

}

and that's it use tooggleable on your click component modifier like here I did on text.